# How to convert TIME to Hours Minute

Tags: dart

I made attendance application. It will record user attendance based on location. I have field in database called `duration_attendance`, this field have type data `TIME`.

This field will record user duration attendance from start work and go home (Example : Start 08:00. End 17:00. It will return duration 08:00)

In Server Side , i can achieved it with:

```
Convert Time To Second : SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('05:15:40');
Convert Second To Hours minute : SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME('48465'),'%Hh %im') // 13h 27m
```

How can i convert **TIME** to Hours and Minutes format in dart side ?

In my case , **duration_attendance** = 08:35 i want convert it to 8 Hours 35 Minutes.

#### Response API

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Data Absensi Bulan 05 Tahun 2020",
    "data": [
        {
            "tanggal_absen": "2020-05-10",
            "jam_absen_masuk": "07:55:00",
            "jam_absen_pulang": "21:22:45",
            "durasi_absen": "13:27:45",
            "status": "o",
            "durasi_lembur": "04:22:45"
        },
        {
            "tanggal_absen": "2020-05-11",
            "jam_absen_masuk": "21:15:10",
            "jam_absen_pulang": "21:15:10",
            "durasi_absen": "00:00:00",
            "status": "a",
            "durasi_lembur": "00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "tanggal_absen": "2020-05-12",
            "jam_absen_masuk": "21:13:01",
            "jam_absen_pulang": "21:13:01",
            "durasi_absen": "00:00:00",
            "status": "a",
            "durasi_lembur": "00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to covert it for display purposes? Check out [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) .It will help you format your DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

My Temporary Solution to my case.

**Work with Format time xx:xx:xx**

```
enum TimeFormat { Jam, JamMenit, JamMenitDetik, Menit, MenitDetik, Detik }

String formatTimeTo(
    String time, {
    TimeFormat timeFormat,
  }) {
    String hour = time.replaceAll(":", "").substring(0, 2);
    String minute = time.replaceAll(":", "").substring(2, 4);
    String second = time.replaceAll(":", "").substring(4, 6);
    String resultHour, resultMinute, resultSecond;
    if (hour.startsWith("0")) {
      resultHour = hour.substring(1);
    } else {
      resultHour = hour;
    }
    if (minute.startsWith("0")) {
      resultMinute = minute.substring(1);
    } else {
      resultMinute = minute;
    }
    if (second.startsWith("0")) {
      resultSecond = second.substring(1);
    } else {
      resultSecond = second;
    }

    switch (timeFormat) {
      case TimeFormat.Jam:
        return "$resultHour Jam ";
        break;
      case TimeFormat.JamMenit:
        return "$resultHour Jam $resultMinute Menit";
        break;
      case TimeFormat.JamMenitDetik:
        return "$resultHour Jam $resultMinute Menit $resultSecond Detik";
        break;
      case TimeFormat.Menit:
        return "$resultMinute Menit";
        break;
      case TimeFormat.MenitDetik:
        return "$resultMinute Menit $resultSecond Detik";
        break;
      case TimeFormat.Detik:
        return "$resultSecond Detik";
        break;
      default:
        return "$resultHour Jam $resultMinute Menit $resultSecond Detik";
    }
  }
```

#### Use

```
print(globalF.formatTimeTo("08:05:55", timeFormat: TimeFormat.JamMenitDetik));
//8 Jam 5 Menit 55 Detik
```

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way is to use the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

You can just define an extension on the Duration so you can easily access your required format across all screens. I would recommend this approach if you have to localize your app.

```
extension ExtensionOnDuration on Duration {
  String get appFormat => DateFormat('h:mm', Platform.localeName)
      .format(DateTime(1111, 1, 1, inHours, inMinutes % 60));
}
```